# How to parse a phone number with only one parenthesis for area code using regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out a way to use regex to fail a certain format of phone number:

(404-555-1212 --> This must fail. but the following formats must pass:

"  (404)   555-1212  "
"(404)555-1212  "
"  404-555-1212 "
"  404-5551212 "
" 4045551212"

Below is my current code which works on all of the above which must pass except the first one. "  (404)   555-1212  ". Essentially I need to fail when there is only one parenthesis and pass when there are two.

```
phone_pattern2 = re.compile(r'\D*(\d{3})[^ .]?(\d{3})[^0-9.]*(\d{4})\D*')

results2 = re.match(phone_pattern2,s2)
print(results2)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
re.search('^((\d{3})|(\(\d{3}\)\s?))-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$', '(404) 555-1212')


if re.search('^((\d{3})|(\(\d{3}\)\s?))-?\d{3}-?\d{4}$', '(404-555-1212'):

    print('Matching')
else:
    print('Fails')
```

Out : Fails

Everything has been solved but two. I've tried different iterations but its like a game of whack a mole. I solve one, another breaks.

```
#Pass cases

# s2 = "  (404)   555-1212  " # solved
# s2 = "(404)555-1212  " # solved
# s2 = "  404-555-1212 "
# s2 = "  404-5551212 " 
# s2 = " 4045551212" # solved

# # Fail cases
# s2 = '+1 (404) 555-3355' #solved
# s2 = '404.555.3355' # solved
# s2 = '404 555-3355' # solved
# s2 = '404 555 3355' # solved
# s2 = '(404-555-1212' # solved

s2 = s2.strip()
s2 = s2.replace("  ","")
print(s2)

phone_pattern2 = re.compile(r'\D*((\d{3})|(\(\d{3}\)\s?))\w?(\d{3})[^0-9.]*(\d{4})\D*')


results2 = re.match(phone_pattern2,s2)
print(results2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. I am trying to get it so that (404-555-1212 fails or returns a match of none.

Comment: It will work... I have updated with your requirement. It fails for '(404-555-1212'

Comment: Thank you very much. This has helped a lot. I just have two cases that I am working on. I've updated the code above with the latest. I am trying to solve for the cases where the number is 404-...

Comment: Any pointers would be appreciated. I think I am very close.

Comment: Which are the patterns you are trying now?